# Simplifying this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{-3}{8v} \frac{dv}{dx} + \frac 1 2 \frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} + 3 \frac{dv}{dx} + \frac 3{8v} \left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2$$

Please help me in this.

I need to simplify this further so that I want to give it in terms of $d^2v/dx^2$ and $dv/dx$. I want to remove that bracket, coz my questions says like have to give it to a form wothout the square of the bracket $dv/dx$. 
Additonal details : I have found that $dv/dx = 4y^3 dy/dx$
I jus want to know how to remove the last term of the expression I have attached.

Comment: I mean how to remove the square of dv/dx. Coz the form I have to give is without it , so if I know how to remove this I will naturally get the form.

Comment: I've edited your question to format the expression in MathJax. Please verify that it says what you intended.

Comment: Yes it is :) thank you :)

Comment: It's equal to 13e^(-4x) , second order differential equation. I didn't mention it's equal to this , because I believe that part is not important to the simplification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions of this ODE can be expressed on the form of $x$ as a function of $v$.

It is doudtfull that the reciprocal function $v(x)$ could be expressed on a closed form in the general case. But a closed form for $v(x)$ is possible in some cases for particular values of the boundary conditions (which are not specified in the wording of the question).

[image]